# Is there a topology which is coarser than the product topology?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a topology which is coarser than the product topology on an infinite Cartesian product of topological spaces?

Comment: We want to put conditions on how it interacts with the topologies on the component spaces.

Comment: In principle also the product topology itself is [coarser](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Coarser_Topology) that the product topology. You probably mean strictly coarser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, the coarsest topology, i.e., the trivial topology.

Note that the product topology is the coarsest topology **for which the projection maps are continuous**. This is very important, and the reason why we care a lot more for this topology than the trivial one!

Comment: sorry, I edited "sets" -> "topological spaces"

Comment: @JayC.Lee This doesn't change my answer as that was how I understood your question in the first place. When you speak of the product topology, you already have a topology for all the factor sets in mind!

Comment: Probably worth noting that ***put a topology on the product*** and ***put a topology on the product so that it interacts nicely with product structure*** are different things.

Comment: thank you for your comments